# Unable to type in password while trying the kendoui registry for angular2

Tags: node.js, npm, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to login using npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress

I am prompted for the the username and I enter it successfully.
Next is password. When I type nothing is seen and I still enter the correct password and hit enter but nothing happens.

Comment: are you running linux distro?

Comment: I am trying to run this on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I downgraded Node from v8.1.1 to v6.9.1 and it fixed the problem.

Comment: strange but yes it fixed it for me too. Thanks!